# Periodic Background Location Updates iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, cllocation

I feel I have read so many posts already on this matter and many of the answers vary which is making things very difficult.

In short I want to update the users location in the background and upload the results to an API periodically (ideally every 90 seconds to 5 minutes). After some digging I have the location updating periodically but the problem occurs when when I come calling a NSOject class which in turn runs a **NSURLSessionDataTask** in the **didUpdateToLocation** (which is only done when an NSDate expired, so not every time the method is called) It times the whole process out.

From testing I have found that usually the device runs this method twice then fails. I am guessing because the OS is telling the app to quite as the call is too heavy.

Below is what my Location method and AppDelegate methods look like...

**AppDelege**

```
-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self applicationUpdateLocationStatus:true];

}
```

-

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    backgroundTask = [[UIApplication  sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{        
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];
        backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

    }];

    [self applicationUpdateLocationStatus:false];

}
```

-

```
-(void)applicationUpdateLocationStatus:(BOOL)foreground {
    backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];
        backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

    }];

    if ([self.location locationAllowed] && [self.user settingsVisible] && [[self.user userAccess] length] > 0) {
          [self.location locationApplicationStatus:foreground];

    }

}
```

**Location Object**

**NOTE**: From other posts starting and stopping the locationManager is apparently key

```
-(void)locationApplicationStatus:(BOOL)forground {
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    [self.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers];
    [self.locationManager setDistanceFilter:5];
    [self.locationManager setPausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically:false];
    [self.locationManager setActivityType:CLActivityTypeOther];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}
```

Here I tried using `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` but it doesn't update frequently enough and the same problem still occurs.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

}
```

-

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    self.nearby = [[NearbyObject alloc] init];

    self.currentLatitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    self.currentLongitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    self.currentAccuracy = newLocation.horizontalAccuracy;

    [self.nearby queryNearby:[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:self.currentLatitude longitude:self.currentLongitude] completion:^(NSError *error, NSArray *content) {
        //SAVE RETURN DATA HERE & EXPIRY
    }];


}
```

**Nearby Object**

```
-(void)queryNearby:(CLLocation *)location completion:(void (^)(NSError *error, NSArray *content))completion {

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{                       
            sessionConfigure = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
            session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfigure delegate:nil delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

            sessionURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@user/usernearby.php" ,APP_BASE_URL]];
            sessionTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:sessionURL completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            //COMPLETION HANDLER OUTPUT 

            }];

            [sessionTask resume];

     }];

}
```

**NOTE**: I have already called `[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];` when the app launches and permission has been granted by the user.

Comment: You are starting long running background tasks in both `applicationDidEnterBackground` and in `applicationUpdateLocationStatus` but in neither case do you end the background task, so this will result in you exhausting your background execution time.

Comment: @Paulw11 where should I be calling this? After the completion handler?

Comment: No, whenever you have completed your background task, so after the data session completed